# Can a class be an Expando and Polymodel in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, expando, polymodel

If I create a PolyModel class, such as Person, can I create an Expando model under that Polymodel?  For instance, a class Male(Person) that was also an Expando model?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [PolyModel documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass.html):

> PolyModel does not support dynamic properties, like Expando does. There is not an equivalent of PolyModel for Expando.

However, there are ways to work around this by using lower-level datastore APIs. They should work fine even with the `PolyModel` class. But the code won't be very nice and I don't recommend it. I don't have time to throw together an example now, but maybe I will tomorrow if noone else does it.

For now you could have a look at a `PolyModel` class I wrote before Google released their own (and yes, the fact that the two have the same name is pure coincidence =), it might inspire you on how to make your own `Expando`-supporting version, should you come up short of other solutions. Here it is: [PolyModel class](http://paste.blixt.org/505) and [PolyModel example](http://paste.blixt.org/506).

Comment: Wow thanks!  I probably will end up working around it, but I still really appreciate the examples.

Comment: I would stop and ask yourself if you really need them first. Expando has very few legitimate use-cases.